# SecurityContextHolder returns null after I call setAuthentication with the custom authentication token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a small Spring Boot project which has username/password authentication. I use spring-security sign-in with our LDAP connection. What I want, and I did manage to do in several projects, is extending AbstractAuthenticationToken class in order to add my own fields.

In my custom GenericFilterBean class, I want to create my own *authentication* object and set into **SecurityContextHolder** as below:

```
KfsMsgToken kfsMsgToken = new KfsMsgToken(
                    kfsInMessageInfo.getObjId(),
                    new ArrayList<>());

SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(kfsMsgToken);
```

And, here is my custom *Authentication* class:

```
public class KfsMsgToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    String kfsInMsgOid;

    public KfsMsgToken(String kfsInMsgOid, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(authorities);
        this.kfsInMsgOid = kfsInMsgOid;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getKfsInMsgOid() {
        return kfsInMsgOid;
    }

    public void setKfsInMsgOid(String kfsInMsgOid) {
        this.kfsInMsgOid = kfsInMsgOid;
    }

}
```

The problem is, after login successfully, I see *UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken* which has been already setted. I reset authentication field using my custom token object, returns null in service layer. I have no idea what is the reason.

All advises are appreciated!

My security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Value("${ldap.urls}")
    private String ldapUrl;
    @Value("${ldap.domain}")
    private String ldapDomain;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/pdf/**").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true).loginProcessingUrl("/login").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider = new
                ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(ldapDomain, ldapUrl);

        return activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

How I register my filter:

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean jwtFilter() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new KfsInMsgFilter(kfsInMessageService, kfsMsgToken, messageChannelService));

        registrationBean.setOrder(0);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns(SECURE);
        registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST);

        return registrationBean;
    }
```

This is what I do in my filter:

```
public class KfsInMsgFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

       ...
            // at this point, Authentication holds UserNamePasswordAuthenticationToken
            KfsMsgToken kfsMsgToken = new KfsMsgToken(
                    kfsInMessageInfo.getObjId(),
                    new ArrayList<>());

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(kfsMsgToken);

       ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Is your custom `GenericFilterBean` is before or after `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProcessingFilter`?

Comment: Since I did not implement the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProcessingFilter and I see UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken in SecurityContextHolder before I change it , It seems before.

Comment: Please post your spring security configuration.

Comment: I have added the config file as you requested.

Comment: Your custom GenericFilterBean is not visible? How did you wire it to the Security filter chain?

Comment: By using *FilterRegistrationBean*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting *authenticated* field over my custom token,

```
kfsMsgToken.setAuthenticated(Boolean.TRUE.booleanValue());
```

solved my problem.

But,

I think there is a better way. Using scoped beans is more efficient and practical.

I changed my custom filter to a request-scoped bean:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class KfsMsgToken {
    String kfsInMsgOid;
}
```

By autowiring, I can get and read the value that I need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and have your custom LDAP authentication inside there and register and finally use

```
http.addFilterAfter(
          new CustomFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but I do not understand how manuel ldap authentication is going to help me? My custom filter works already after authentication. Even if I did that, how am I going to accomplish setting my custom authorization token into SecurityContextHolder ?